# view do angular imprime [object, Object] com ngFor

Tags: json, angularjs

Estou montando uma aplicação onde preciso listar o histórico das posições e estados do maquinário.

estou com dificuldades em manipular o  que vem do arquivo `.json` para poder imprimir na tela com *ngFor... o `console.log(data)` retorna o array correto na devtools , mas na hora de jogar na view, equipmentID imprimi corretamente, mas o atributo states imprimi [object,Object] para cada  item do  array.

não consegui

o arquivo json ->

```
"equipamentStateHistory": [{
        "equipmentId": "a7c53eb1-4f5e-4eba-9764-ad205d0891f9",
        "states": [
            {
                "date": "2021-02-01T03:00:00.000Z",
                "equipmentStateId": "03b2d446-e3ba-4c82-8dc2-a5611fea6e1f"
            },
            {
                "date": "2021-02-01T07:00:00.000Z",
                "equipmentStateId": "baff9783-84e8-4e01-874b-6fd743b875ad"
            }]
         }
        ]
```

estou fazendo a requisição desta forma

Service do get

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CargoTruckHistory } from 'src/app/models/cargo-truck-history.model';
import { Response } from './response';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CargoTruckHistoryService {
  baseApiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/equipamentStateHistory';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

  getHistory(): Observable<CargoTruckHistory[]> {
    return this.http.get<CargoTruckHistory[]>(this.baseApiUrl);
  }
}
```

component.ts que recebe os dados

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CargoTruckHistory } from 'src/app/models/cargo-truck-history.model';

import { History } from 'src/app/models/history.model';
import { CargoTruckHistoryService } from '../services/cargo-truck-history.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-historic-cargo-truck',
  templateUrl: './historic-cargo-truck.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./historic-cargo-truck.component.css'],
})
export class HistoricCargoTruckComponent implements OnInit {
  historicos: History[] = [{ historico: 'Estado' }, { historico: 'Posição' }];
  stateHistories: CargoTruckHistory[] = [];

  states = [];
  states_list = [];
  baseApiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/equipamentStateHistory';
  constructor(private cargoTruckHistoryService: CargoTruckHistoryService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stateHistories;
    this.stateList();
  }

  stateList(): CargoTruckHistory[] {
    this.cargoTruckHistoryService.getHistory().subscribe((data) => {
      this.stateHistories = data;

      console.log(data);
    });
    return this.stateHistories;
  }
}
```

view do componente onde é feito o loop ->

```
<nav class="historic-input-wrapper">
  <ng-select
    class="select-box"
    name="historico"
    [items]="historicos"
    bindLabel="historico"
    placeholder="Selecione um histórico"
  ></ng-select>
</nav>
<div
  class="container-history-state"
  *ngFor="let stateHistory of stateHistories"
>
  <p>ID do Equipamento :{{ stateHistory.equipmentId }}</p>
  <p>{{ stateHistory.states }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara acho que já é a décima pergunta com Angular relacionada ao mesmo problema que comento aqui, parece que o pessoal tá precisando estudar um pouco melhor estrutura de dados. Aqui `this.stateHistories = data;` vc está atribuindo a variável **stateHistories** tudo o que retorna da API, porém os dados que precisa para iterar no **ngFor** está dentro da propriedade **equipamentStateHistory**, é esse array que precisa acessar, então basta fazer **`this.stateHistories = data.equipamentStateHistory`** ou no html **`*ngFor="let stateHistory of stateHistories.equipamentStateHistory"`**

Comment: eu entendi o que quis dizer mas me desculpe se for ignorância minha, eu joguei numa variável a url que bate direto no na propriedade equipamentStateHistory...
na "baseApiUrl", quando dou console.log na data ele me retorna o array que está dentro da propriedade que preciso de forma correta, não seria esse o processo?montei o json com propriedades separadas para poder ter rotas diferentes.